# Trouble with cyrillic in paired list in R

Tags: r, list, cyrillic

I have problem in R with cyrillic symbols in paired lists (dictionaries?):

e.g.:

```
switch("привет", "color" = "red", "shape" = "square", "привет" = 5) #result should be 5 but isn't 

switch("color", "color" = "red", "shape" = "square", "привет" = 5) # works fine

datatable(df, colnames=c('Дата1' = 'date1', 'Дата2' = 'date2') # doesn't work ("<U+0414>..." instead of "Дата1")
```

UTF-8 is used in code, other situations with Cyrillic are handled properly.

Comment: What do you expect the first example to do? Pure numbers cannot be used as symbols in R.

Comment: From which package is `datatable`?

Comment: @Roland, it works without quotes if not cyrillic, e.g. switch("foo","foo" = 5, ...), datatable is from DT

Comment: I can confidently say that `... -> 5` does not work in R.

Comment: @Roland, I am sorry, 
switch("привет", "color" = "red", "shape" = "square", "привет" = 5)  is to give result 5 ("->" is used without sense of R operator)

Comment: Do `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian")`  (on Windows, see the documentation for other OS) and it works as expected with `switch`.

Comment: @Roland, thank you, but it works in ordinary script (case 1) and doesn't work in shiny app where I render datatable from DT (case 2)

Comment: @Roland, it works in both cases, great! Thank you!